# Connect to postgres from docker-compose for metabase and postgres using secrets file for credentials

Tags: postgresql, docker, metabase

I have metabase with postgres up and running with this docker-compose file:

```
$ cat docker-compose.yml
version: '3.7'
services:
  metabase-secrets:
    image: metabase/metabase:latest
    container_name: metabase-secrets
    hostname: metabase-secrets
    volumes:
    - /dev/urandom:/dev/random:ro
    ports:
      - 3000:3000
    environment:
      MB_DB_TYPE: postgres
      MB_DB_DBNAME: metabase
      MB_DB_PORT: 5432
      MB_DB_USER: /run/secrets/db_user
      MB_DB_PASS: /run/secrets/db_password
      MB_DB_HOST: postgres-secrets
    networks:
      - metanet1-secrets
    depends_on:
      - postgres-secrets
    secrets:
      - db_password
      - db_user
  postgres-secrets:
    image: postgres:latest
    container_name: postgres-secrets
    hostname: postgres-secrets
    environment:
      POSTGRES_USER: /run/secrets/db_user
      POSTGRES_DB: metabase
      POSTGRES_PASSWORD: /run/secrets/db_password
    networks:
      - metanet1-secrets
    secrets:
      - db_password
      - db_user
networks:
  metanet1-secrets:
    driver: bridge
secrets:
   db_password:
     file: db_password.txt
   db_user:
     file: db_user.txt
```

I'm unable to connect to postgres instance in order to get a database dump for backup purposes.
Each time I run psql, using root or postgres user, I get same error "role does not exist".

These are the running processes:

```
$ docker-compose top
metabase-secrets
UID     PID      PPID    C    STIME   TTY     TIME                                                                            CMD
--------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------
2000   256298   256273   10   09:11   ?     00:01:15   java -XX:+IgnoreUnrecognizedVMOptions -Dfile.encoding=UTF-8 -Dlogfile.path=target/log -XX:+CrashOnOutOfMemoryError -server -jar /app/metabase.jar

postgres-secrets
  UID       PID      PPID    C   STIME   TTY     TIME                                  CMD
------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------
gkrellmd   256139   256114   0   09:11   ?     00:00:00   postgres
gkrellmd   256258   256139   0   09:11   ?     00:00:00   postgres: checkpointer
gkrellmd   256259   256139   0   09:11   ?     00:00:00   postgres: background writer
gkrellmd   256260   256139   0   09:11   ?     00:00:00   postgres: walwriter
gkrellmd   256261   256139   0   09:11   ?     00:00:00   postgres: autovacuum launcher
gkrellmd   256262   256139   0   09:11   ?     00:00:00   postgres: stats collector
gkrellmd   256263   256139   0   09:11   ?     00:00:00   postgres: logical replication launcher
gkrellmd   256429   256139   0   09:12   ?     00:00:00   postgres: /run/secrets/db_user metabase 172.18.0.3(60194) idle
gkrellmd   256430   256139   0   09:12   ?     00:00:00   postgres: /run/secrets/db_user metabase 172.18.0.3(60196) idle
gkrellmd   256431   256139   0   09:12   ?     00:00:00   postgres: /run/secrets/db_user metabase 172.18.0.3(60198) idle
gkrellmd   256432   256139   0   09:12   ?     00:00:00   postgres: /run/secrets/db_user metabase 172.18.0.3(60200) idle
```

Please ignore "gkrellmd" above. It's the user name for user id "999" on docker's host machine.

I started shell in the container and tried to connect to the database:

Here my tries from within the container:

```
$ docker-compose exec postgres-secrets bash
root@postgres-secrets:/# psql
psql: error: FATAL:  role "root" does not exist
root@postgres-secrets:/# cat /etc/passwd | grep postgres
postgres:x:999:999::/var/lib/postgresql:/bin/bash
root@postgres-secrets:/# su postgres
postgres@postgres-secrets:/$ psql
psql: error: FATAL:  role "postgres" does not exist
```

The files, containing the secrets, are where expected:

```
postgres@postgres-secrets:/$ ls /var/run/secrets/ -la
total 20
drwxr-xr-x 2 root root 4096 Sep 16 13:08 .
drwxr-xr-x 1 root root 4096 Sep 16 13:08 ..
-rw-rw-r-- 1 1000 1000   13 Sep 16 12:51 db_password
-rw-rw-r-- 1 1000 1000   13 Sep 16 12:51 db_user
```

These are the postgres-secrets log during container startup:

```
$ cat pg_logs.txt
Attaching to postgres-secrets
postgres-secrets    | The files belonging to this database system will be owned by user "postgres".
postgres-secrets    | This user must also own the server process.
postgres-secrets    |
postgres-secrets    | The database cluster will be initialized with locale "en_US.utf8".
postgres-secrets    | The default database encoding has accordingly been set to "UTF8".
postgres-secrets    | The default text search configuration will be set to "english".
postgres-secrets    |
postgres-secrets    | Data page checksums are disabled.
postgres-secrets    |
postgres-secrets    | fixing permissions on existing directory /var/lib/postgresql/data ... ok
postgres-secrets    | creating subdirectories ... ok
postgres-secrets    | selecting dynamic shared memory implementation ... posix
postgres-secrets    | selecting default max_connections ... 100
postgres-secrets    | selecting default shared_buffers ... 128MB
postgres-secrets    | selecting default time zone ... Etc/UTC
postgres-secrets    | creating configuration files ... ok
postgres-secrets    | running bootstrap script ... ok
postgres-secrets    | performing post-bootstrap initialization ... ok
postgres-secrets    | syncing data to disk ... ok
postgres-secrets    |
postgres-secrets    | initdb: warning: enabling "trust" authentication for local connections
postgres-secrets    | You can change this by editing pg_hba.conf or using the option -A, or
postgres-secrets    | --auth-local and --auth-host, the next time you run initdb.
postgres-secrets    |
postgres-secrets    | Success. You can now start the database server using:
postgres-secrets    |
postgres-secrets    |     pg_ctl -D /var/lib/postgresql/data -l logfile start
postgres-secrets    |
postgres-secrets    | waiting for server to start....2021-09-16 13:08:35.427 UTC [48] LOG:  starting PostgreSQL 13.4 (Debian 13.4-1.pgdg100+1) on x86_64-pc-linux-gnu, compiled by gcc (Debian 8.3.0-6) 8.3.0, 64-bit
postgres-secrets    | 2021-09-16 13:08:35.437 UTC [48] LOG:  listening on Unix socket "/var/run/postgresql/.s.PGSQL.5432"
postgres-secrets    | 2021-09-16 13:08:35.481 UTC [49] LOG:  database system was shut down at 2021-09-16 13:08:34 UTC
postgres-secrets    | 2021-09-16 13:08:35.491 UTC [48] LOG:  database system is ready to accept connections
postgres-secrets    |  done
postgres-secrets    | server started
postgres-secrets    | CREATE DATABASE
postgres-secrets    |
postgres-secrets    |
postgres-secrets    | /usr/local/bin/docker-entrypoint.sh: ignoring /docker-entrypoint-initdb.d/*
postgres-secrets    |
postgres-secrets    | 2021-09-16 13:08:36.280 UTC [48] LOG:  received fast shutdown request
postgres-secrets    | waiting for server to shut down....2021-09-16 13:08:36.285 UTC [48] LOG:  aborting any active transactions
postgres-secrets    | 2021-09-16 13:08:36.287 UTC [48] LOG:  background worker "logical replication launcher" (PID 55) exited with exit code 1
postgres-secrets    | 2021-09-16 13:08:36.289 UTC [50] LOG:  shutting down
postgres-secrets    | 2021-09-16 13:08:36.320 UTC [48] LOG:  database system is shut down
postgres-secrets    |  done
postgres-secrets    | server stopped
```

And these are the last ones:

```
postgres-secrets    | PostgreSQL Database directory appears to contain a database; Skipping initialization
postgres-secrets    |
postgres-secrets    | 2021-09-28 12:11:54.810 UTC [1] LOG:  starting PostgreSQL 13.4 (Debian 13.4-1.pgdg100+1) on x86_64-pc-linux-gnu, compiled by gcc (Debian 8.3.0-6) 8.3.0, 64-bit
postgres-secrets    | 2021-09-28 12:11:54.811 UTC [1] LOG:  listening on IPv4 address "0.0.0.0", port 5432
postgres-secrets    | 2021-09-28 12:11:54.811 UTC [1] LOG:  listening on IPv6 address "::", port 5432
postgres-secrets    | 2021-09-28 12:11:54.821 UTC [1] LOG:  listening on Unix socket "/var/run/postgresql/.s.PGSQL.5432"
postgres-secrets    | 2021-09-28 12:11:54.842 UTC [26] LOG:  database system was shut down at 2021-09-28 12:11:37 UTC
postgres-secrets    | 2021-09-28 12:11:54.872 UTC [1] LOG:  database system is ready to accept connections
postgres-secrets    | 2021-09-28 12:25:01.343 UTC [82] FATAL:  role "root" does not exist
postgres-secrets    | 2021-09-28 12:25:30.002 UTC [96] FATAL:  role "postgres" does not exist
```

My intention is to get a database dump in order to restore it in another instance of postgres.

I'd got all my books burned. :-(
Any suggestion is welcomed!

Answer (score 0):

You can try something like this:

```
docker exec -t postgres-secrets pg_dumpall -c -U /run/secrets/db_user > dumpall.sql
```